# Given two vector spaces, $V$, $W$ defined by basis vectors with the same $span$, does $V = W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I'll list the following definitions to aid this question

> **Definition (Basis)**: A basis for any vector space, is a set of vectors that has two properties at once:
>
> 1. The vectors are linearly independent
> 2. The vectors span the space

-

> **Definition (Span)**: A set of vectors *spans* a space if their linear combinations fill the space

---

Now let's say I have the following two vector spaces, $V$ and $W$ defined as follows:

$$V := \left\{\lambda\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix} + \beta\begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix} \Bigg\vert \ \lambda,\beta \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

where $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix} \text{and} \begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix}$ are *linearly independent*

$$W := \left\{\lambda\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} + \beta\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix} \Bigg\vert \ \lambda,\beta \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

It's clear to see *(well because the vector spaces $V$ and $W$ are literally defined by the basis vectors)* that the basis vectors for $V$ and $W$ are

$$B_V = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}c\\d\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

$$B_W = \left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

Now their respective $span$'s are obviously the vector spaces they *define* $V$ and $W$;

$$span(B_V) = V \ \ \ \   \text{and} \ \ \ \ span(B_W) = W$$

But by the following theorem (which you can view in this question here: [If $n$ vectors are linearly independent, is their span $\mathbb{R}^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/810551/266135))

$$span(B_V) = \mathbb{R^2} \ \ \ \   \text{and} \ \ \ \ span(B_W) = \mathbb{R^2}$$

And by the definition of *basis* and *span*, these two sets of *bases* both are linearly independent and both *span* $\mathbb{R^2}$, but does that not imply that $$V = W = \mathbb{R^2}$$

---

It seems intuitively, that $V$ and $W$ must be two different vector spaces as if I define $V$ as follows, substituting scalars in for $a, b, c,d$:

$$V := \left\{\lambda\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix} + \beta\begin{bmatrix}2\\5\end{bmatrix} \Bigg\vert \ \lambda,\beta \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$
 it doesn't seem at all clear that $V = W$ from this definition of $V$.

For $V = W$ to be true, I'm assuming that there must be some theorem stating the following:

$$\text{Is this a theorem:}\ \ \ V = W \iff span(B_v) = span(B_w)$$

---

So just to wrap up my post in 3 short questions:

- <strike>Does $V = W = \mathbb{R^2}$ in the example I gave</strike> (Yes it does, answered below)

  - Are there stricter, definitions of *basis*, *span* that are not defined in terms of each other (I've taken these definitions from *Introduction to Linear Algebra by G Strang*)
  - Do I have any apparent misconceptions about *basis* and *span*?

---

**EDIT (IMPORTANT):** What if I define $V$ and $W$ to be two *different* two-dimensional planes (vector spaces with *dimension* $2$) in $\mathbb{R^3}$? In other words the basis vectors of $V$ and $W$ will $span$ two different two-dimensional vector spaces, (two different planes in $\mathbb{R^3}$)

$$V := \left\{\lambda\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix} + \beta\begin{bmatrix}d\\e\\f\end{bmatrix} \Bigg\vert \ \lambda,\beta \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

where $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c \end{bmatrix} \text{and} \begin{bmatrix}d\\e\\f \end{bmatrix}$ are *linearly independent*

$$W := \left\{\lambda\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} + \beta\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} \Bigg\vert \ \lambda,\beta \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

In this case $W$ is the $xy\text{-plane}$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$, whereas $V$ is an arbitrary plane also in $\mathbb{R^3}$

In this case (it's again obvious what the basis vectors are, so I won't put them here):

$$span(B_w) = span(B_v) = \mathbb{R^2}$$

But in this example I'm certain $V \neq W$, as although their $span$'s are equal the *orientation* of the planes (the vector spaces) in $\mathbb{R^3}$ are different.

So there are one of four possibilities for *this case*

1. $V = W$ and *orientation* of $n$-dimensional vector spaces in $n+1$-dimensional vector spaces does not break the equality of two $n$-dimensional vector spaces with the same $span$
2. The theorem I linked above is missing a condition for equality of two vector spaces, which this example exploits
3. The $span$ of $n$ linearly independent vectors does not output the orientation of the $n$-dimensional space ($\mathbb{R^n}$) created by the $n$ basis vectors in $n+1$ dimensional space ($\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$)
4. I have a misconception of one or more of the concepts in this post.

Comment: About the first question: base vectors of V are linear combinations of W-base vectors. Isn't still evident that V = W?

Comment: To everyone reading this question, I apologize in advance for the long length of this question, as I realize that most question on Math.SE are far shorter, but this was the only I could get my point across

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov, see my *edit* above, in this case the $span$ of $V$ adn $W$ are the same, but you can't write the basis vectors of $V$ as linear combinations of $W$'s basis vectors

Comment: after your _edit_: what do you mean by tellling span(B_v)=span(B_w)=R^2. What is R^2 here then?

Comment: @DenisKorzhenkov, then in my edited example does $span(B_v) \neq span(B_w) \neq \mathbb{R^2}$? I assumed the equivalence based on my proposed theorem which one of the answers verified to be correct.

Comment: sure. A span is a set. If the element of the first span doesn't belong to the second span then they aren't equal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45271/discussion-between-denis-korzhenkov-and-perturbative).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, $V=W=\mathbb{R}^2$ in your example.

2) The concepts of  span and basis are independent. The span is defined for  any set of vectors (also non linearly independent) and it is the vector spave generated by the vectrors in the set.

A basis is a set of **linearly independent** vectors and, as any set of vectors, it generates a vector space that is its span.

Comment: thanks for your answer, please see the revised **edited** portion of my question at the bottom of the OP, as I give another example picking on the theorem I proposed.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^3$ contains infinitely many subspace tha are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ ( the planes containing the origin) and any such subspace is the span of a couple of linearly independent vectors that is a basis for this subspace. 
A plane is also the span of any set of vectors contained in the plane, but in these sets only two vectors are linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

From your observation:

$$span(B_V) = V \ \ \ \   \text{and} \ \ \ \ span(B_W) = W,$$

your proposed theorem follows quickly. If $V=W$, then $span(B_V) = V = W = span(B_W)$, and conversely.

Your notions of basis and span appear to be pretty good. Basis is defined in terms of span, but span is not defined in terms of basis, so there's no circularity issue.

I think you got this.

Edit: In your later example, neither $V$ nor $W$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$. They are different 2-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$, both of which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, as is any real 2-dimensional vector space, but neither of them contains any element of $\mathbb{R}^2$. A common misconception is that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$; it is not.

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs, thanks for your answer, please see the revised **edited** portion of my question at the bottom of the OP, as I give another example picking on the theorem I proposed.