# On picking a basis in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Given a finite dim. arbitrary vector space $V$, is picking a basis the same as picking an isomorphism into the set of $n$-tuples?

This really confuses me, everyone seems to pass to vectors without caring that the actual sets are different.

Comment: This two questions I asked yesterday and the previous day might be of some help: (1) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1924289/basis-span-and-equivalence-of-vector-spaces and (2) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923803/given-two-vector-spaces-v-w-defined-by-basis-vectors-with-the-same-span I went through the *exact* same confusion you went through.

Comment: @Perturbative There are alot of questions in those posts. I cant find an answer to mine tho, they might be very close tho but I cant really se it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n = \dim V$. Picking an isomorphism $V \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is the same as picking an *ordered* basis of $V$.

If you have an isomorphism $f\colon V \to \mathbb{R}^n$, define $v_i \in V$ as the unique vector of $V$ such that $f(v_i) = e_i$, for all $i = 1, \dotsc, n$. Since $f$ is an isomorphism, $\{v_1, \dotsc, v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$. Then you can endow it with the natural order, i.e. $(v_1, \dotsc, v_n)$ is the ordered basis.

If you have an ordered basis $(v_1, \dotsc, v_n)$ of $V$, then there is a unique linear map $f\colon V \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(v_i) = e_i$ for all $i = 1, \dotsc, n$. Since $\{ e_1, \dotsc, e_n \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f$ is an isomorphism. Notice here that we need the basis of $V$ to be ordered, otherwise we could choose many different isomorphisms.

Once you have fixed either an ordered basis of $V$ or the corresponding isomorphism $f\colon V \to \mathbb{R}^n$, you can *identify* each vector $v$ with $f(v)$. This is convenient because it allows you to treat any finite-dimensional vector space *as* a space of $n$-tuples (which are easy to handle on paper). But of course $v$ and $f(v)$ are *actually* different objects.

Comment: Note: when you write down a particular basis of $V$, it will look ordered. But by definition, a basis is just a _set_ of vectors. For example, if $\{v_1, v_2\}$ is a basis of $V$, then $\{v_2, v_1\}$ is the _same_ basis, even if it's written in a different way. Fixing a particular order on a basis matters precisely when you want to represent vectors as $n$-tuples. If you choose $(v_1, v_2)$ as your ordered basis, then $(1, 0)$ represents $v_1$; if you choose $(v_2, v_1)$, then $(1, 0)$ represents $v_2$.