# Basis, Span and Equivalence of Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, vectors

This question here, forms the basis (no pun intended) of the question I'm asking below : [If $n$ vectors are linearly independent, is their span $\mathbb{R}^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/810551/266135)

---

Firstly if I have

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a \\ a\end{bmatrix} \ \text{and} \ \  A' = \begin{bmatrix}a \\ a\\ a\end{bmatrix}$$

Does $span(A) = span(A') = \mathbb{R^1}$? According to the question I've linked above it does.

Secondly can we define a vector space in the following way?

$$V := span\{b_1, b_2, b_3, ...,b_n\}$$

where $b_i$ are the basis vectors for $V$.

---

If both of the above premises are true, does that not imply that the vector space created by the basis vector $A$ and the vector space created by the vector $A'$ are equivalent?

To show this, we let

$$V = \left\{\lambda\begin{bmatrix}a\\a\end{bmatrix}  \Bigg\vert \ \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

$$V' = \left\{\lambda\begin{bmatrix}a\\a\\a\end{bmatrix}  \Bigg\vert \ \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$

Now $\dim(V) = 1$ and $\dim(V')=1$, they are both one-dimensional vector spaces. But $V$ is a one-dimensional vector space in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $V'$ is a one-dimensional vector space in $\mathbb{R^3}$, intuitively they *shouldn't* be equivalent.

But according to our definition of vector spaces $V = V' = \mathbb{R^1}$ as $span(V) = span(V') = \mathbb{R^1}$

According to this definition of a vector space, we could then define two different planes (two-dimensional vector spaces where $\dim(W) = 2$ and $\dim(W') = 2$), with different *orientations* in $\mathbb{R^3}$ and they would be *equivalent* vector spaces.

We could generalize and take it even further and define two different hyperplanes, with completely different orientations, where $\dim(H) = n$ and $\dim(H') = n$ in $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ and $H = H'$ by our definition, which obviously cannot be true.

---

So my question boils down to this, how can we relate the concepts of *span* and *basis* in terms of the *definition* of a vector space, and how can we relate them so that contradictions like I've shown in examples above do not occur, when we try to equate two vector spaces.

If you can identify any misconceptions I may have, please let me know!

Comment: There is a huge difference between "equals" and "isomorphic to"

Comment: @UmbertoP. could you explain further please?

Comment: Your claim that $\mathrm{span} V = \mathbb R^1$ is incorrect. No element of $V$ belongs to $\mathbb R$ despite the obvious correspondence between the two spaces.

Comment: @UmbertoP, is $span(V)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^1}$ or is $V$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must note that $A$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^2$ and $A'$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^3$. That being said, the span of $A$ is not the same as the span of $A'$ because they live in different spaces!

However, there is some sense in which these spans are the "same." Consider that for any vector $v \in \operatorname{span}A$, $v = \lambda(a, a)$ for some $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. Similarly, for any vector $u \in \operatorname{span}A'$, $u = \mu(a, a, a)$ for some $\mu \in \Bbb R$. Both vectors, though they live in different spaces, effectively encode *one piece of data*, namely the number $\lambda a$ or $\mu a$.

More precisely, we say there is an *isomorphism*, or a *relabeling* of these spaces with the set of real numbers, $\Bbb R$. That is, for any real number $r$, there is a vector in $\operatorname{span} A$ and $\operatorname{span} A'$ such that the components of that vector are each the number $r$. Similarly, given a vector in $\operatorname{span} A$ or $\operatorname{span} A'$, we can find a real number that is equal to that vector's single piece of data.

It is not the case that the span of *any vector* in $\Bbb R^2$ or $\Bbb R^3$ is equal to $\Bbb R$, but it is the case that they can be *isomorphic* to $\Bbb R$.

In symbols, we write
$$
\operatorname{span}A \cong \operatorname{span}A' \cong \Bbb R.
$$

To address your main question, the definition of a vector space is a set closed under an addition $+$ and scalar multiplication $\cdot$ such that various other conditions hold. The glaring issue with your saying that $\operatorname{span}A$ and $\operatorname{span}A'$ are equal is that we *cannot* add vectors in $\operatorname{span}A$ and $\operatorname{span}A'$, so this does not respect closure under addition.

Since not both of your premises are true, the conclusion that $\operatorname{span}A$ and $\operatorname{span}A'$ are *equal* is invalid. The conclusion that they can be *isomorphic* is valid, as I have described.

Comment: So let's say I have a vector space defined in the following way $$V = \left\{\lambda\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\a\end{bmatrix} \ \ s.t. \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\ \right\}$$, which would be a line (a one-dimensional vector space with $\dim V = 1$) in $\mathbb{R^3}$. Now what you are saying is that $V$ is *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{R^1}$ and not equal to it, correct?

Comment: @Perturbative Yes that is correct.

Comment: AOrtiz then let's say I have another vector space defined in this way  $$V = \left\{\lambda\begin{bmatrix}a\end{bmatrix} \ \ s.t. \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\ \right\}$$, in this case is $V$ still *isomorphic* to $\mathbb{R^1}$? As it seems intuitively that $V$ should *equal* $\mathbb{R}$. How can we tell then if a vector space like, the one I gave above is ever actually *equal* to $\mathbb{R}$ and not just *isomorphic*?

Comment: @Perturbative *That* set is also not equal to $\Bbb R$. That set is the set of all $1\times 1$ matrices with real values. However, the association between that set $V$ and $\Bbb R$ is very natural. In general, the set $\Bbb R$ is *unique* up to isomorphism. That is, there is only one *complete ordered field* up to isomorphism. There are many ways of associating $\Bbb R$ with other sets, but there is only *one* $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Ah okay, I see your point now, just out of curiosity where (in which book) did you first encounter isomorphisms? I'm reading through *Introduction to Linear Algebra by G Strang* and there's nothing mentioned about it. Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: @Perturbative Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* covers isomorphisms in some detail, and it is the context in which I first encountered them. There is a section on isomorphisms in linear algebra in this free online textbook: http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-IVLT.html which you may be interested in. Glad to help!

Comment: Thanks for that. Just one last question, is there anything wrong with defining vector spaces as I did, in terms of the span of its basis vectors? : $$V:= span\{b_1, b_2, \ ... \ b_n\}$$ Is it formally correct? I'm familiar with the definition that a vector space is the set of all $n$-tuples with respect to a basis field, but they way I've defined it in terms of the span of its basis vectors is pretty much the same thing I would think.

Comment: @Perturbative In fact, *all finite dimensional vector spaces* may be defined as the span of a set of vectors. I recommend to you *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Axler. Your foundations will be strong if you read from Axler's text. The span is itself the set of all linear combinations of the vectors in the span. You don't really need to ask if this is a vector space since it is straightforward to show that the span of a set of vectors satisfies the defining characteristics of a vector space and thus is indeed a vector space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45330/discussion-between-perturbative-and-aortiz).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your confusion comes from the improper use of the terms ''equivalent'', ''equals'' and ''isomorphic'', referred to a vector space.

**Equals** means that the two vector spaces are the same space. So, a plane, as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, is equal only to itself.

**Equivalent** is not a defined word in this context, in the sense that to say that two vector space are equivalent has not a defined meaning, also if I can understand the you are using this word in the sense of ''isomorphic'', that is:

**Isomorphic** means that there is a function betwee the two spaces $V$ and $W$ that is one-to-one and onto and preserve the structure of the space $V$ in the sense that 
$$
f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) \quad \mbox{and} \quad f(kx)=kf(x)
$$
Note that this imlpies that the two vector spaces must to be defined over the same fileld $\mathbb{F}$  such that $kx$ and $kf(x)$ ($k\in \mathbb{F}$) are well defined.

Given this, the kay fact is that:

> two vector space that have the same finite dimension $n$ are isomorphic. And this means that they are spanned by basis that have the same number of vectors.

This does not means that they are the same space in a concrete way, but this means that, in an abstract way, they are essentially the ''same space'' also if they are not equals. This is the case of two subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of the same dimension  or also of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ ( the plane $x-y$) and a subspace of dimension two in any vector space  $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Finally note that two vector spaces can be isomorphic also if the element of the spaces are not $n-$ples of real numbers. E.g. The set of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$, as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and to the vector space of the polynomial of degree at most $1$  in $\mathbb{R}$ ( the polynomial $ax+b$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$).

So the correct statement is:

> If $n$ vectors are linearly independent,  their span is **isomorphic to** $\mathbb{R}^n$!