# I want to know If n vectors is linearly independent, their dimension is n

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

is it always possible?
(I don't know the basic concept)

My question is same as 
"If n vectors are linearly independent, is their span R^n"
this question??

Comment: Can you please phrase your question in a more understandable manner? As it is, this does not really make sense. I presume that you wanted to ask ‘If a vector space is of dimension n and I have a set of n vectors that are linearly independent, does that set form a basis for the vector space?’. If that is what you wanted to ask, edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if the vectors have $n$ coordinates ! It's true ! By the definition of being independent.
Find the solution here : [If $n$ vectors are linearly independent, is their span $\mathbb{R}^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810551/if-n-vectors-are-linearly-independent-is-their-span-mathbbrn?rq=1)

Comment: thanks, Then, the comment"If the vectors have n coordinates"is not in the question
the question is false?

Comment: Hum... Yeah but you will figure out quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ the span is exactly $\mathbb R^n$ whereas, if you have $n$ linearly independent vectors in some real vector space $V$ then the span of those vectors is linearly isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

In general, in any vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb F$ span of any $n$-linearly independent vectors form a subspace $\mathbf{isomorphic}$ to $\mathbb F^n$.