# Orthogonal and orthonormal for dot-product

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, orthonormal, change-of-basis

Consider the vectors $
u_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\ 
-1
\end{pmatrix},u_2=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
2\\ 
4
\end{pmatrix},u_3=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
-1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix} $ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

and the map

$f:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $f(x)=u_1\left \langle u_1, x \right \rangle + u_2\left \langle u_2, x \right \rangle + u_3\left \langle u_3, x \right \rangle$

Show that the family of vectors $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ is a orthogonal family with respect to the dot-product in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and that it is a basis. Is it a orthonormal basis?

I know that we say that 2 vectors are orthogonal if they are perpendicular to each other. i.e. the dot product of the two vectors is equal to zero. Would I just have to simply apply the inner product on my space pairwise and conclude that it is equal to 0?

I know that an orthonormal basis for an inner product space with finite dimension is a basis for the space whose vectors are orthonormal i.e they are all unit vectors and orthogonal to each other.

Even though I seem to get the concepts and the thinking behind I do not know how to apply it in this example.

Comment: What is the role of $f$ in the question???

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net your guess is as good as mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that the vectors are an orthogonal family, yes you just have to apply the dot product pairwise and show that each pair of vectors has a dot product of $0$.

To next argue that the vectors form a basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$, recall that a set of orthogonal vectors, none of which are the zero vector, is linearly independent. So $\{ u_1, u_2, u_3\}$ is a set of three linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$, and hence a basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Finally, to check whether it is an *orthonormal* basis, you just have to check whether the norm of all the vectors is $1$ (equivalently whether $u_i\cdot u_i = 1$ for all $i=1,2,3$). Since $u_1\cdot u_1 = 3 \ne 1$, this is not the case. Hence the basis is not orthonormal.

Comment: for point 2 "To next argue that the vectors form..." Is that all? Do they not have to have any other property?

Comment: Correct, because if you have three linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$, then they must form a basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$. See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810551/if-n-vectors-are-linearly-independent-is-their-span-mathbbrn

Comment: I showed this using Gaussian elimination making the matrix of the 3 vectors into the identity matrix and thus it must be a basis.

Comment: But regarding your last step on norm. Why are you using the dot procut on  the same vector? I am getting root 3 for the norm of the first vector.

Comment: *"I showed this using Gaussian elimination making the matrix of the 3 vectors into the identity matrix and thus it must be a basis."* -- You can definitely do this as well, but it takes longer than necessary here. Once you have shown that the three vectors are linearly independent, you immediately can deduce that they form a basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$, because of what I linked above.

Comment: *"But regarding your last step on norm. Why are you using the dot procut on the same vector?"* Because for the set of vectors to be orthonormal, it must be the case that $u_i \cdot u_i =1$ for all $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: *"I am getting root 3 for the norm of the first vector."* -- This is right, remember that the norm of a vector $v\in \Bbb{R}^{n}$ is equal to $\sqrt{v\cdot v}$. So $v$ has a norm of $1$ if and only if $v\cdot v =1$.

Comment: Oh so for orthonomal step I just have to use the dotproduct of the same vector on it self. I.e this fails for the very first one since it is bigger than 1.

Comment: May I ask you something A bit related in terms of the function in the post? How would I find a Matrice $B$ to represent this map with  respect to the standard basis for both domain and codomain?

Comment: You can do it using the standard method to find the matrix of a linear transformation with respect to standard basis in domain and codomain. Namely, $B$ will be a $3\times 3$ matrix where the $j$-th column is equal to $f(e_j)$ for $j=1,2,3$. (Here, $e_j$ refers to the $j$-th standard basis vector for $\Bbb{R}^{3}$.)

Comment: So evaluate the standard basis vectors in teh function and then assign them into a 3 times 3 matrix according to their index? And if the basis switches to i.e the vectors we are dealing with in this post would this be the same?

Comment: $\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal{B}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathcal{C}}$In general if you want the matrix of $f$ with respect to (ordered) basis $\B$ in the domain and $\C$ in the codomain, the desired matrix's $j$-th column will be $\left[f(b_j)\right]_{\C}$, where $b_j$ is the $j$-th vector from $\B$ and $\left[f(b_j)\right]_{\C}$ is the *coordinate vector of $f(b_j)$ with respect to $\C$*. So in other words to get the desired matrix, you have to evaluate $f$ at the basis vectors of the domain and then express the results as coordinates with respect to the codomain's basis.

Comment: But if both basis for the domain and codomain are the same this should just leave us with the part of evaluating our vectors in the function and forming the representing matrix, right?

Comment: That is true in your case since the basis for the codomain is the standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that orthogonality means $\langle u_1,\,u_2\rangle=\langle u_2,\,u_3\rangle=\langle u_3,\,u_1\rangle=0$. As @MinusOne-Twelfth explained, the thogonality of $n$ nonzero vectors in $\Bbb R^n$ ensures they form a basis. For orthonormality, check whether $\langle u_1,\,u_1\rangle=\langle u_2,\,u_2\rangle=\langle u_3,\,u_3\rangle=1$; you should find this fails.